# Assign Bang argument programmatically?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not successful in using the Bang (!) operator without it's argument being hardcoded, i.e., `Me.VBProject.References!Excel`. In this example, the *Excel* reference is hardcoded.
Out of frustration I've tried all permutations I can think of in an attempt to utilize it:

```
[Me.VBProject.References!(str)]
[Me.VBProject.References! & (str)]
["Me.VBProject.References!" & str]
["Me.VBProject.References!" & (str)]
```

and many more with parens added to ensure proper pre-evaluation including the longhand `Application.evaluate` method. Nada!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

The bang operator is just a shortcut for calling the default member of the object, and passing the text after the bang as a string to the first parameter of the default member:

The bang notation:

```
Me.VBProject.References!Excel
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```
Me.VBProject.References.Item("Excel")
```

and, because it is the default member, you can omit the `Item` function call:

```
Me.VBProject.References("Excel")
```

So, to use your (really badly named) variable `str`:

```
str = "Excel"
Debug.Print Me.VBProject.References.Item(str).Name
```

Comment: So there isn't any way to escape the variable, so that it's interpreted as a variable and not a hard coded string argument?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach yes, yes there is. That's what `Me.VBProject.References.Item(str)` is doing.

Comment: The question asks specifically about the bang operator, you provide useful info, but it doesn't answer OP's question.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach What part doesn't answer the OP's question? I explain how the bang operator works, and what an exact alternative is that will achieve the outcome he is seeking. There is no other way to get the reference other than enumerating the references and checking each name. That *might* work with the references collection, but it won't work with the Workbooks or Worksheets collections. Passing the variable as an index will allow the OP to achieve his desired outcome.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach if this doesn't answer OP's question, then OP's question is not answerable. The bang operator is not magic.

Comment: Well, Bang it! ;) My question was indeed targeted more towards Bang itself. It is odd to me that it does not seem to permit a variable as its string literal.

Answer (score 2):

This is an X-Y problem.

#### Bang notation is a means to an end.

It's one of the tools made available to you, to **retrieve an item from a collection**.

Nothing more, nothing less.

> What you want isn't to *use the bang operator with a variable*.
>   What you want is to *retrieve an item from a collection using a variable*.

Collection types have a *default member*, typically named `Item`. Default members can be specified explicitly, or implicitly accessed:

```
Dim foo As New Collection
foo.Add Item:=42, Key:="test"
```

```
Debug.Print foo.Item("test") 'explicit reference to the default member
Debug.Print foo("test") 'implicit reference to the same default member
```

The bang operator is just another way to make an implicit call to the collection's default member:

```
Debug.Print foo!test
```

All 3 `Debug.Print` statements above will call the `foo.Item` default member to output the `42` associated with the key `"test"`.

#### Square brackets

As you can see, what comes immediately after the `!` operator is really a **string literal**. Because a string literal can contain whitespace, the VB6/VBA parser needed a way to support them.

That's what the `[square brackets]` are for:

```
foo.Add 72, "spaces in the key"
Debug.Print foo![spaces in the key]
```

When they're not delimiting a string literal for bang notation, square brackets are *usually*<sup>1</sup> interpreted as a run-time expression for the host application to evaluate. For example this is legal (though questionably advisable) in Excel VBA:

```
Debug.Print [A1]
```

The VBA parser identifies a *bracketed expression* and defers its evaluation to the host application - here Excel; **at run-time**, the instruction ultimately equates to:

```
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
```

If you don't believe the evaluation of a *bracketed expression* is deferred to the host application, consider what needs to happen for this instruction to print `4`:

```
Debug.Print [Sum(2,2)]
```

Therefore, every single one of the attempts/permutations in your post missed the mark and made *Excel* try to evaluate an expression that only VBA would be able to resolve, because `Me.VBProject.References` means absolutely nothing to Excel.

Square-bracket expressions should usually be avoided, because you lose compile-time checks and any error can only be caught at run-time.

---

<sup>1</sup>*Usually*, because they can also be used in *some* identifiers,
 for example in `Enum` types, to make a `[_hidden]` enum member.

---

## Bottom Line

Bang notation is a way to retrieve an item from a collection by leveraging *default members* and making string literals *look* like an identifier. You can't make it work without "hard-coding" the string literal, because it **requires a *string literal***.

**If you want to parameterize the collection retrieval, you can't use the bang operator.**

It's useful for *typing the code faster*. If you don't know *exactly* how it works and what it does for you though, it's a double-edged blade that **hides what's really going on** and ultimately makes the code harder to read and understand. Code shouldn't be written just to be *run*. Code should be written to be *read* and *understood*.

---

Note: Bang notation isn't *actually* only for collections. It actually passes its argument as a string literal to the first parameter of anything that has a default *member*. I would strongly advise avoiding it for anything other than a collection class though (e.g. `Collection.Item`, `Workbooks.Item`, `Worksheets.Item`, `Recordset.Fields`, etc.), for the sake of future maintainers' sanity.

Comment: Bang notation is for passing a string literal `argument` as the 1st parameter to the default member of **any** `object`, not just collections. *Some* collections expose a default member that accepts an index, so bang notation is often *interpreted* as being a collection feature, but not all collections have a default member, and some have a default member that is *not* an indexer. A non-collection object can have a default member that accepts a string parameter, and using bang notation when working with those objects is perfectly valid. http://bytecomb.com/the-bang-exclamation-operator-in-vba/

Comment: @ThunderFrame Waaattttt???!?!!!! Gosh this is terrible. "Perfectly valid", sure - and *perfectly insipid* too. May that knowledge be lost forever.

Comment: VBA would be so much less insipid if `:`, `!` and ` _` were illegal characters.